# How to correctly extract a header from a multiline column names table in a .txt file?

Tags: python, list

So,I believe my title may be a little confusing so I'll elucidate the problem I have at hands with the header in question:

[image: Header from table of interest]

I'll write it here too but I don't know if it'll be in the same format as in the image:

```
   X---X------------X----X---X---X---X---X------X------X-----X-------X------X------X------X------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-X
    Num     Nome     Ssis Pos Usi Usi Usi Volume Volume Vutil  Previs  Pinst Perdas  Qtur   Qdef   Vert    Produt  Somprd  Produt  Somprd T
          da Usina        Vaz Jus Des Jus Maximo Minimo  Inic   Oper          Hid   Maxima Minima  Maximo   Eqv     Eqv    65% VU  65% VU I
                              Ope Ope Ene   hm3    hm3    %             MW   % - M   m3/s   m3/s   m3/s    MJ/m3   MJ/m3   MJ/m3   MJ/m3  P
   X---X------------X----X---X---X---X---X------X------X-----X-------X------X------X------X------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-X
```

The header I ultimately want is

```
    header = ['Num','Nome da Usina', 'Ssis', 'Pos Vaz', 'Usi Jus Ope', 'Usi Des Ope', 'Usi Jus Ene', 'Volume Maximo hm3', 'Volume Minimo hm3',
              'Vutil Inic %', 'Previs Oper', 'Pinst MW', 'Perdas Hid % - M', 'Qtur Maxima m3/s', 'Qdef Minima m3/s', 'Vert Maximo m3/s',
               'Produt Eqv MJ/m3', 'Somprd Eqv MJ/m3', 'Produt 65% VU MJ/m3', 'Somprd 65% VU MJ/m3', 'T I P']
```

Now, I'm limited to not using any Python libraries such as pandas or numpy or regex, only using buit-in functions to read the .txt file and extract the info. I need to extract the header correctly so as to produce a more general data_extraction function, since now I'm having to manually define headers from the two tables I'm interested in, and then proceeding to extract the relevant data:

```
def extract_data_from_table4(table_lines):
    line_length = 21
    header = ['Num','Nome da Usina', 'Ssis', 'Pos Vaz', 'Usi Jus Ope', 'Usi Des Ope', 'Usi Jus Ene', 'Volume Maximo hm3', 'Volume Minimo hm3',
              'Vutil Inic %', 'Previs Oper', 'Pinst MW', 'Perdas Hid % - M', 'Qtur Maxima m3/s', 'Qdef Minima m3/s', 'Vert Maximo m3/s',
               'Produt Eqv MJ/m3', 'Somprd Eqv MJ/m3', 'Produt 65% VU MJ/m3', 'Somprd 65% VU MJ/m3', 'T I P']
    data = []
    for line in table_lines[3:]:
        values = extract_values_from_line(line)
        row_data = {}
        for i in range(line_length):
            row_data[header[i]] = values[i]
        data.append(row_data)
    return data
```

As to the `extract_values_from_line(line)` function I'm using in there, it is as follows:

```
def extract_values_from_line(table_line):
    line_length = 21
    values = table_line.strip().split()
    for i in range(line_length):
        if values[i] == 'm':
            values[i-1] += ' m'
            values.remove(values[i])
    return values
```

The split method turns my string into an array of substrings separating each one by a whitespace, which generates a problem since one of the values in my table is written as "0.1 m", 'm' being the unit of measure. If I simply use `table_line.strip().split()`, in this example, the value "0.1 m" in my values list would be fragmented into two, "0.1" and "m". What I'm doing is correcting that, although I'm more than open to suggestions on how to better handle this. Lastly, it's my very first time posting a question so I'm sorry if there's any lacking information beforehand.

I've tried left padding the first three table_lines that are read with " ", which correspond to the header I'm interested in extracting, so that I am able to actually join those table_lines into my header, but I haven't been able to progress much thinking like this.

Comment: It looks like the X values in the 1st and 4th lines are indicating columns of delineation between each column name. Have you considered to read the 1st line, identify the columns (character count) that contain the Xs? WIth that info, you likely can parse the 2nd and 3rd lines based on character count, and combine all the text from 2nd line (e.g., between columns 6-15) with the same character positions from the 3rd line.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, although I can't say for sure how to parse the 2nd and 3rd lines yet. Something in the lines of defining each column delineation based on the number of character count each column has, and proceeding to somehow splitting the 2nd and 3rd table_lines based on said number ? For example, observing the first line of X values, the first column 'Num' has a character count of 3, while 'Nome da Usina' has a character count of 12. How would I go about to splitting them based on this number, though ?

Answer (score 1):

Having the line with `-` and `x` to delimit the column names is very helpful. First, parse that line to get the location of each `x`. Then, read the next few lines until you see another line with only `-` and `x`. These lines need to be split at the same indices at which you see an `x` in the first line

```
with open(filename) as f:
    first_line = next(f)
    # Parse first line, find indices of X
    split_indices = [i for i, c in enumerate(first_line) if c == 'X']

    col_header_lines = []
    col_names = []

    line = next(f)
    # Append to col_header_lines until you find another line that isn't all - and X
    while not all(c == '-' or c == 'X' for c in line.strip()):
        col_header_lines.append(line)
        line = next(f)

    # Read col names out of col_header_lines
    # For each line in col_header_lines
    # Take the substring between consecutive elements of split_indices
    # Then join the substring on each line with spaces, and strip extra whitespace
    for start_index, end_index in zip(split_indices, split_indices[1:]):
        # start_index and end_index contain consecutive elements of split_indices
        col_name = " ".join(
                h_line[start_index+1:end_index].strip()  # substring between indices
                for h_line in col_header_lines           # of all lines in col_header_lines
            ).strip()
        col_names.append(col_name)
```

Now, `col_names` contains the desired column names:

```
['Num',
 'Nome da Usina',
 'Ssis',
 'Pos Vaz',
 'Usi Jus Ope',
 'Usi Des Ope',
 'Usi Jus Ene',
 'Volume Maximo hm3',
 'Volume Minimo hm3',
 'Vutil Inic %',
 'Previs Oper',
 'Pinst  MW',
 'Perdas Hid % - M',
 'Qtur Maxima m3/s',
 'Qdef Minima m3/s',
 'Vert Maximo m3/s',
 'Produt Eqv MJ/m3',
 'Somprd Eqv MJ/m3',
 'Produt 65% VU MJ/m3',
 'Somprd 65% VU MJ/m3',
 'T I P']
```

If the rest of the lines in the file don't have delimiters, you can also use the `split_indices` to split those lines:

```
    # in the same with block as above
    other_rows = []
    for line in f:
        row = []
        for start_index, end_index in zip(split_indices, split_indices[1:]):
            row.append(line[start_index+1:end_index].strip())
        if row:
            other_rows.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the `'X'` characters in the table header delineate the column boundaries. Find those bounds, extract the text within each column, and recombine them into a single string label.

```py
header = """   X---X------------X----X---X---X---X---X------X------X-----X-------X------X------X------X------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-X
    Num     Nome     Ssis Pos Usi Usi Usi Volume Volume Vutil  Previs  Pinst Perdas  Qtur   Qdef   Vert    Produt  Somprd  Produt  Somprd T
          da Usina        Vaz Jus Des Jus Maximo Minimo  Inic   Oper          Hid   Maxima Minima  Maximo   Eqv     Eqv    65% VU  65% VU I
                              Ope Ope Ene   hm3    hm3    %             MW   % - M   m3/s   m3/s   m3/s    MJ/m3   MJ/m3   MJ/m3   MJ/m3  P
   X---X------------X----X---X---X---X---X------X------X-----X-------X------X------X------X------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-X"""
rows = header.splitlines()

# find the indices of where 'X' occurs in the first line
idx = [i for i, c in enumerate(rows[0]) if c == 'X']

import itertools
def pairwise(iterable):  # this is included in itertools Python 3.10
    # pairwise('ABCDEFG') --> AB BC CD DE EF FG
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

# create a slice for each column boundary
bounds = [slice(p[0]+1, p[1]) for p in pairwise(idx)]

# extract the piece of each label from the 3 rows of text using the slices
segments = []
for row in rows[1:4]:
    segments.append([row[b].strip() for b in bounds])

# join each column's label segments together
labels = [' '.join(x).strip() for x in zip(*segments)]
print(labels)
```

```
['Num', 'Nome da Usina', 'Ssis', 'Pos Vaz', 'Usi Jus Ope', 'Usi Des Ope', 'Usi Jus Ene', 'Volume Maximo hm3', 'Volume Minimo hm3', 'Vutil Inic %', 'Previs Oper', 'Pinst  MW', 'Perdas Hid % - M', 'Qtur Maxima m3/s', 'Qdef Minima m3/s', 'Vert Maximo m3/s', 'Produt Eqv MJ/m3', 'Somprd Eqv MJ/m3', 'Produt 65% VU MJ/m3', 'Somprd 65% VU MJ/m3', 'T I P']
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is essentially the same strategy as other have used but I hope it is a little easier to follow. It also uses no `imports`.

```py
rows = """
X---X------------X----X---X---X---X---X------X------X-----X-------X------X------X------X------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-X
 Num     Nome     Ssis Pos Usi Usi Usi Volume Volume Vutil  Previs  Pinst Perdas  Qtur   Qdef   Vert    Produt  Somprd  Produt  Somprd T
       da Usina        Vaz Jus Des Jus Maximo Minimo  Inic   Oper          Hid   Maxima Minima  Maximo   Eqv     Eqv    65% VU  65% VU I
                           Ope Ope Ene   hm3    hm3    %             MW   % - M   m3/s   m3/s   m3/s    MJ/m3   MJ/m3   MJ/m3   MJ/m3  P
X---X------------X----X---X---X---X---X------X------X-----X-------X------X------X------X------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-------X-X
""".strip().split("\n")

## ----------------------
## obtain the starting and ending indexes of our data from the first line
## ----------------------
indexes = [i for i, v in enumerate(rows[0]) if v == "X"]
indexes = [(start+1, end) for start, end in zip(indexes, indexes[1:]) if end is not None]
## ----------------------

## ----------------------
## initialize a list of empty strings
## ----------------------
headers = [""]*len(indexes)
## ----------------------

## ----------------------
## for rows other than the first or last
## use the data indexes to pick out the data parts
## append each part to its respective header entry
## ----------------------
for row in rows[1:-1]:
    parts = [row[start:end].strip() for start, end in indexes]
    headers = [f"{h} {p}".strip() for h, p in zip(headers, parts)]
## ----------------------

print(headers)
```

This will give you:

```
['Num', 'Nome da Usina', 'Ssis', 'Pos Vaz', 'Usi Jus Ope', 'Usi Des Ope', 'Usi Jus Ene', 'Volume Maximo hm3', 'Volume Minimo hm3', 'Vutil Inic %', 'Previs Oper', 'Pinst MW', 'Perdas Hid % - M', 'Qtur Maxima m3/s', 'Qdef Minima m3/s', 'Vert Maximo m3/s', 'Produt Eqv MJ/m3', 'Somprd Eqv MJ/m3', 'Produt 65% VU MJ/m3', 'Somprd 65% VU MJ/m3', 'T I P']
```